# crontab day of month not working

Tags: cron

My crontab is working even too much: today is the 21th (of november, 2015) and both of these lines gets executed. I really cannot figure out why.

```
* * 1 * 0,6 echo "test in dom" >> /opt/testweekend
* * * * 0,6 echo "test" >> /opt/testweekend
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, 21 Nov 2015, is a Saturday, so the second is clearly eligible to run.  But the first is, also; the `man` page for `crontab(5)` says that

> Note:  The  day of a command's execution can be specified in the
>   following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day
>          of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the "*" character), the command will be run  when
>          **either** field matches the current time.  For example,
>          `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

Thus your first entry will run every minute of every Saturday and Sunday, **and** every minute of the first of every month.